# Visual Basic 6.0 cannot compile Collection on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb6

I'll try to be brief: We have code written in Visual Basic 6.0 that I am trying to compile on a Windows 7 64-bit computer.  (Previously this was compiled on an old XP computer.) Most of the code seems to compile correctly, however certain code that has Attributes, like the NewEnum, are not honoring the VB attribute.  Here is an example:

The VB6 method looks like this:

```vb
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
    'this property allows you to enumerate
    'this collection with the For...Each syntax
    Set NewEnum = mCol.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

This is default Enumerator that is created when you use the `Class Builder Utility`.

However, the Attribute elements are not honored when the code is compiled.  Using the OLE View program, it shows that the Attributes are ignored.

The XP computer produces the following snippet:

```
[id(0xfffffffc), propget, hidden]
HRESULT NewEnum([out, retval] IUnknown** );
```

But the Windows 7 computer generates:

```
[id(0x68030000), propget]
HRESULT NewEnum([out, retval] IUnknown** );
```

I have attempted to set the Visual Basic application to run in XP (Service Pack 3) Compatibility mode and this has not helped.

Because of the size and complexity of our application we cannot port it from VB6 to .NET at this time, and we need to get it to compile. Does anyone know how to properly configure VB6 so that it will properly compile a collection?

Comment: None of this has anything to do with the OS involved or any appcompat shims applied to it.  If you don't have a "Vista-aware" manifest you get XP shims except for version-lie.  On later OSs lack of supportedOS elements in the manifest (if any) cause the other downlevel shims to be applied.  So you never want to force-fit compatibility shims via file Properties anyway.  More likely if there is a real difference it is related to VB6 Service Packs not being applied.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I have installed the service packs, when VB6 starts it notes that it is running SP6 (the latest). I reformatted the machine again, and this time it works. I don't get it.

Comment: I'm puzzled as well.  I suppose it might be some subtle difference in the installation procedure or different SP6 releases (I've seen them as high as a 6d).